# I want to delete files from SFTP folder using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, sftp, winscp

I have written some code but not working please suggest me how can I handle.

```
Function SFTPDelete(SFtpServerName, SFtpUser, SFtpPassword, LocalFolderPath, SFTPOutFolderPath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim mydate, mmddyyyy, sFTPScript, rc
    Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    rc = micPass
    mydate = Date - 1
'    mmddyyyy = Right("00" & Month(mydate),2) &"-"& Right("00" & Day(mydate),2) & "-" & CStr(Year(mydate))

    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option batch on" & vbCrLF
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option confirm off"& vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "option transfer binary" & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "open sftp://" & SFtpUser & ":" & SFtpPassword & "@" & SFtpServerName & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & SFTPOutFolderPath  & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "delete" & SFTPOutFolderPath & vbCRLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "close" & vbCrLf
    sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "exit" & vbCrLf

    sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
    sFTPTempFile = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName

    'Write the input file for the sftp command to a temporary file.
    Set oFTPScript = oFTPScriptFSO.CreateTextFile(sFTPTempFile, True)
    oFTPScript.WriteLine(sFTPScript)
    oFTPScript.Close
    Set oFTPScript = Nothing

    sCmd = """C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe""  /console /log=" & LocalFolderPath & "log_winscp_get_files.log /loglevel=1 -script=" & sFTPTempFile
    oFTPScriptShell.Run sCmd

    Wait 10
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Error occured while delete file from FTP location ["& SFTPOutFolderPath&"] "
        rc = micFail
    Else
        'oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(LocalFolderPath&"log_winscp_get_files.log")
    End If

    ' Get rid of temp file used for input to sftp
    oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(sFTPTempFile)

    Set oFTPScriptFSO = Nothing
    Set oFTPScriptShell = Nothing
    SFTPDownload = rc
End Function
```

Please let me know what changes I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague.

But there are at least two obvious problems:

- There's no `delete` command in WinSCP. There's [`rm` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm).
- You are missing a space after the `delete` command (that should be `rm` command).
- The path in the `rm`/`delete` command is redundant to the `cd` command and will actually delete the folder itself. If you want to delete only the file in the folder, use just `*` mask:

  ```
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "rm *" & vbCRLf
  ```
- You are missing the [`-hostkey` switch in the `open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey) to [verify server hostkey](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).